# Changes to Twython in effect of Twitter REST API version change

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, twython

I have been trying to extract data from the Twitter API using Twython. Recently, the Twitter API changed version from v1 to v1.1. I do not understand the changes (if any) that need to made in the usage of Twython. I use Twython 2.5.5. The commands I used to use before, are suddenly not working anymore.  Please help me with this transition so that I can get my work done faster. Thanks in advance.

This is the code snippet I am using:

```
twitter = twython.Twython(oauth_token = oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = oauth_secret, app_key = oauth_consumer_key, app_secret = oauth_consumer_secret)
twitter.getRetweets(id="123")
```

This is the error I am being shown:

```
TwythonError: 'Unauthorized: Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect. -- An error occurred processing your request.'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the guidelines for asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added a code snippet to highlight the specifics of the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming to this question way late, but if you (or anyone else) has further issues with this, I believe it's due to the OAuth verifier changes that Twitter (somewhat) recently introduced. Twython supports this in the newer versions, and **[we have examples](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/)**:

```
from twython import Twython

t = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
auth_tokens = t.get_authorized_tokens(oauth_verifier)
print auth_tokens
```